# Create and refresh materialized view on oracle

Tags: database, oracle, materialized-views

i have a question.
When i create or refresh a oracle materialized view, the source tables origin are locked in read or write operations?

If i doing insert operation on the one of table source while dbms refreshing materialized view what happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle enforces statement-level read consistency, which means that when you run a statement, the data is consistent as at the start of the statement (or transaction, depending on your transaction isolation level), meaning that any changes made to the data being queried won't be seen by the current statement.

I highly recommend that you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT020) regarding how Oracle keeps things consistent.